# SQL Validation Check

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to implement data check validation control in Sql.

Similar to if I have PA12345 - Output I am looking for is CCNNNNN.

In my head, I am think of using replace function but not sure what will be the optimised procedure for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* I followed you correctly, you can use `regexp_replace()` twice:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col, '[a-z]', 'C', 1, 0, 'i'), '\d', 'N') newcol from t
```

The inner invokation turnes all alphabetics characters to `'C'`, then the outer invokation turns digits to `'N'`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9313e6b2c7e449a4483fd0b8d97fe811)**:

```
with t as (select 'PA12345' col from dual)
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col, '[a-z]', 'C', 1, 0, 'i'), '\d', 'N') newcol from t
```

```
| NEWCOL  |
| :------ |
| CCNNNNN |
```

Note, however, that this is not *validation*, but rather transcoding. If what you want is validate that the format of the string matches a predefined pattern, then you would rather use `regexp_like()`:

```
regexp_like(col, '[a-z]{2}\d{5}', 'i')
```